# Update Multiple Python Variables With Single Function and Different Kivy Buttons

Tags: python, kivy

I'm wanting to replace the 7 functions I have

```
OLD
def press_saturday(self, *args):
    if self.set_saturday == '0':
        self.set_saturday = '1'
    else:
        self.set_saturday = '0'
```

with a single function that updates the correct variable, based on the button that is pressed.

```
NEW
def alarm_wkdy(self, value, day):
    if value == '0':
        value = '1'
    else:
        value = '0'
```

kivy button

```
OLD
Button:
                id: 'saturday'
                text: "S"
                font_size: 20
                size_hint: .1, .12
                pos_hint: {'x': .65, 'y': 0}
                on_press: root.manager.press_saturday(*args)
                background_color: root.manager.set_saturday, 0, 0, root.manager.set_saturday

NEW
Button:
    id: 'saturday'
    text: "S"
    font_size: 20
    size_hint: .1, .12
    pos_hint: {'x': .75, 'y': 0}
    value: root.manager.set_saturday
    day: 'set_saturday'
    on_press: root.manager.alarm_wkdy(self.value, self.day)
    background_color: root.manager.set_saturday, 0, 0, root.manager.set_saturday
```

The goal being to update self.set_*whatever* when the corresponding button is pressed.
Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend removing the global variables from inside your functions, stop reading '1' and '0' as strings and switch to boolean negation, and instead return the value(s) you desire. It appears you want to return the switched value 1/0, as well as the day of week, so I would return them as a tuple like so:

```
class myclass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def alarm_wkdy(self, value, day):
        return (not value, day)

c = myclass()
print(c.alarm_wkdy(True,'Wednesday'))
(False, 'Wednesday')
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I use the values as 0/1 because I use them in the buttons' colors, to indicate their status. I don't really like the default look of the ToggleButton widget.

*edit, getting used to the keyboard functions of this site

Answer (score 0):

I decided to stop being a boob and instead of calling a function to do the job I just put the logic where it should be, in the button itself.

```
Button:
                id: 'saturday'
                text: "S"
                font_size: 20
                size_hint: .1, .12
                pos_hint: {'x': .75, 'y': 0}
                on_press: root.manager.set_saturday = str((int(root.manager.set_saturday) -1) * -1)
                background_color: root.manager.set_saturday, 0, 0, root.manager.set_saturday
```